# Eclipse 3.7 Indigo-'Install new software' not progressing : GWT Designer

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, gwt-designer

I am really stressed with Installing any new software/plugin into my eclipse. The Install new software just does not work for me ! It goes upto a certain point and just stops there..
I am not able to install new plugin through eclipse, I have to get the zip file and put the plugins and features into respective folders and restart eclipse.

I have no idea why is this the case ? No issue with firewall and internet I guess.
There are some plugins like GWT designer which needs to be installed using Eclipse only and does not get properly installed via zip file extraction.

Anyone had similar issues??

Comment: Are you sure you don't need to have a proxy set up? I had the same problem where the install would only get to 50% before hanging, and setting the proxy fixed it.

Comment: Have you tried running Eclipse.exe in Admin mode, does this still happen?

Comment: I am trying running as Admin now.. lets see what happens

Comment: @SumDeos How to set the proxy ?? can you tell me ?

Comment: @AnujKulkarni "Go to Window > Preferences > General > Network Connections". From there you can configure Eclipse to use your proxy settings.

Comment: Afaik apart from .metadata folder in the workspace directory eclipse does not leave much traces in the system what means that you probably don't want to install it but just unpack it and run it in different workspaces.

Comment: @SumDeos Yes in that window how to exactly do proxy settings ?

Comment: @AnujKulkarni First set the proxy to be "Manual". Then you just need to select whatever kind of proxy you use (HTTP, HTTPS, SOCKS) and put in the authentication information. If any other software you use requires a proxy to connect to the internet, then that is the same information you will enter here.

Comment: @SumDeos It is already there... I guess some other issue.. because anyways it was fetching data from the internet to show marketplace softwares

Comment: The cause of problem was AVG Antivirus

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cause of problem was AVG Antivirus which was blocking the installation. So in the future  take care that you don't have an antivirus program running on your computer that will block installing software in Eclipse.