# GWT, GWT Designer and Eclipse Plugin Issue

Tags: java, eclipse, gwt, eclipse-plugin, gwt-designer

I am learning GWT, so I am following this tutorial from Google GWT 
https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/tools/gwtdesigner/tutorials/stockwatcher

In this I have to open a java file in design mode. 
There I am getting the error

java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.gwt.dev.shell.designtime.HostedModeSupportImpl

I installed GWT designer via zip file, unzipping it and extracting it in the plugins and features folder.

Is it correct way ? is that the reason why the java file is not opening in design mode?

Also, I am not able to install a new software in eclipse, 
See my question ->

[Eclipse 3.7 Indigo-'Install new software' not progressing : GWT Designer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11232486/eclipse-3-7-indigo-install-new-software-not-progressing-gwt-designer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cause of the problem was AVG Antivirus blocking the installation. Make sure you don't have an antivirus running on your computer that will block software installations on Eclipse.